# How to Use Nested Attribute's Method from ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

In `application_controller` if I do:

```
  def calendar_sidebar
    @missed_dates_by_date = current_user.missed_dates.group_by {|i| i.date_missed.to_date} if current_user # I'm trying to call `missed_dates` method `date_missed`
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today if current_user
  end
```

I get `undefined method 'missed_dates'`.

This is because:

```
[1] pry(main)> MissedDate.last
 id: 3,
 user_id: nil,
```

I don't know how to make the user_id NOT `nil` or if there is another way to go about this.

MissedDate `belongs_to :level` and Level `belongs_to :habit` and Habit `belongs_to :user` which does have a `user_id` associated with it.

As a newbie I pictured in my mind that something like this would have worked:

```
@missed_dates_by_date = current_user.habits.levels.date_missed.group_by {|i| i.date_missed.to_date}
```

But that gave `undefined method 'levels'`

**_calendar.html.erb**

```
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %>
    <ul>
      <% @missed_dates_by_date[date].each do |missed_dates| %> # This is what I'm trying to get it to work for so that I can show in a calendar the date_missed
        <%= missed_dates.date_missed %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an association through another association, we must declare it in the model specifying the [`:through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) option, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :habits
  has_many :levels, through: :habits
  has_many :missed_dates, through: :levels
end
```

This way, ActiveRecord knows how to associate missed dates with a user and can retrieve them automatically (without a `user_id` field on `MissedDate`):

```
current_user.missed_dates.where(attribute: value)
```

You should probably remove `user_id` from `MissedDate` to avoid confusion with a migration like so:

```
def up
  remove_column :missed_dates, :user_id
end

def down
  # insert the code to re-create the column
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never understood what `through` was for until now :]

Answer (score 2):

You get error undefined method `missed_dates` because your user don't have this association.

You should create User model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :missed_dates
end
```

And your MissedDate model:

```
class MissedDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

After this you can create associations objects:

```
@user = User.new
@user.missed_dates << MissedDate.new
```

Comment: I already had that. eirikir gave me the answer. Thanks for your help though :]

Comment: Yes, I saw it after I had posted my answer.